# captcha image in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, gd, captcha

I have the following code,but what I got is broken link ! I have installed GD library and the proper font ! but nothing work ,so how to I can use image captcha in zendframework without broken link ,what the wrong ?

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('Captcha',array(
        'captcha' => array('captcha' => 'Image', 'wordLen' => 6, 
        'timeout' => 300, 'width' => 300, 'height' => 100, 
        'imgUrl' => '/captcha',
        'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha', 
        'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/fonts/LiberationSansRegular.ttf')));
```

//sorry

Comment: @sam, please post the code you're mentioning, otherwise nobody's going to be able to help you out with correcting it ;)

Comment: Have you looked at your error logs?  Also, you can view image by right clicking and viewing.  Often times that will give you a hint as to what the problem is.  More detail would be helpful.

Comment: so sorry for that I have edit it now !

Comment: any error? what broken link says?

Comment: i got instead of captcha a broken image !

Comment: @sam. Need more details. Are your images actually created? What urls do you get now, and what they really should be, is your app in a subfolder, e.g. www.site.com/myzfapp/public?

Comment: i have captcha folder in public and font folder , actually i have put the captcha within a form i got every thing correct but the captcha i got exactly a broken image as when u put img tage and there is no image in the proper location that what i got BROKEN IMAGE !

Comment: ok since its not clear ,what it should be imageUrl in the code ? why is used anything else i know about it !

Comment: Your imageUrl is fine I think, although possibly there should be a trailing slash. But please answer these two questions: 1. Are the images being created? (i.e. in your public/captcha directory are there image files) 2. What URL is the image tag linking to when you view the form? (view the page source to check)

Comment: Well i have run into similar problem, I use the imgDir as APP_PATH./data/captcha/images, also checked if images are created. Now i think the problem is with the imgUrl, which might not bypass the ACL and does not render the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
'/public/captcha'
```

Instead of:

```
APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha'
```

--

What I did in my application was add a couple of lines in the main index.php file to have direct access to the `public` folder using a constant variable:

```
// Define path to public directory
defined('PUBLIC_PATH')
    || define('PUBLIC_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../public'));
```

Then just use:

```
PUBLIC_PATH . '/captcha'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.. It comes from : )

```
        if ( in_array( strtolower( ini_get( 'magic_quotes_gpc' ) ), array( '1', 'on' ) ) ) {
        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
        $_GET = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET );
        $_COOKIE = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_COOKIE );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha' must exist and apache/php must have write access to it.